# Quran Surah Anbiya Ayat 30 - a Rhetorical Question?

Tags: quran, tafseer

Assalamu Alaikum Brothers in Islam,

> "Do not the Unbelievers see that the heavens and the earth were joined
>   together (as one unit of Creation), before We clove them asunder? We
>   made from water every living thing. Will they not then believe?

Is this is a rhetorical device?

Comment: Brother Ive edited the question. is the ayat in question an example of a rhetorical question?  Or is it literal?